# Navigation resize after certain DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm building a personal website and I want to make my navigation to shrink after I scroll down. The website consists of 4 divs with 100% height. Right now I am using a JS, that is shrinking the navigation after 300px scroll:

```
 <script>
   function init() {
     window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
          var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
              shrinkOn = 300,
              header = document.querySelector("header");
          if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
              classie.add(header,"smaller");
          } else {
              if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                  classie.remove(header,"smaller");
              }
          }
      });
  }
  window.onload = init();
</script>
```

My question is how to make the navigation to shrink after the first div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `offsetTop` to get the y-coordinate of the `div`, if you want to shrink your navigation when the top border of window touches the top border of the `div` then you can set your `shrink` variable value as -

```
shrink = div.offsetTop;
```

however if you want to shrink that after crossing the `div` then you can set the value of `shrink` to this -

```
shrink = div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am not sure if I did it right, but I couldn't make it work. However I used
'shrinkOn = slide_one.clientHeight,' and it works perfect.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Licheff it works perfect (if you have used it correctly), see here a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/L6cgmu33/ when the top border of `first` div touches the top window then the `shrink` class is added to `#nav`

Comment: @Licheff see this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/L6cgmu33/1/ this one adds the class 'shrink' when the user has scrolled to the bottom border of the `first` div, and I don't think the `clientHeight` solution will work, try setting margin-top on the first div and then see, I think it will not work, also try changing the height of your first div, in both cases that will fail, but you can experiment on my fiddle, change the height of the `#first` or change anything, it will work!

Comment: It turns out that i misspelled my div's name. Right now I settled with `shrinkOn = slide_one.clientHeight,` and I put a bottom border on my div and it is working perfectly. The thing is that I am using ready-made scripts for the JS part, because I am not familiar with the syntax. All in all, right now is working perfectly. Thank you very much for the advises and the solutions that you've given!

Comment: @Licheff you're welcome!!, I have provided you with two ways how you want to shrink (after the first div goes offscreen or top of the window touches top of the `div`), use whichever you want, and let me know if any problem you face..

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
shrinkOn = firstDiv.clientHeight
```